# How to count the number of time intervals that meet a boolean condition within a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas `df` with a time series in `column1`, and a boolean condition in `column2`. This describes continuous time intervals that meet a specific condition. Note that the time intervals are of unequal length.

```
Timestamp   Boolean_condition
1           1
2           1
3           0
4           1
5           1
6           1
7           0
8           0
9           1
10          0
```

**How to count the total number of time intervals within the whole series that meet this condition?**

The desired output should look like this:

```
Timestamp   Boolean_condition   Event_number
1           1                   1
2           1                   1
3           0                   NaN
4           1                   2
5           1                   2
6           1                   2
7           0                   NaN
8           0                   NaN
9           1                   3
10          0                   NaN
```

Comment: After seeing jezrael's anwer, it inspired me to work even harder and as a result I've come up with an even faster solution but using `numpy` instead. You need not accept mine though, but this is just to show you various perspectives/approaches to handle the same problem at hand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create `Series` with [`cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.cumsum.html) of two `masks` and then create `NaN` by function [`Series.mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.mask.html):

```
mask0 = df.Boolean_condition.eq(0)
mask2 = df.Boolean_condition.ne(df.Boolean_condition.shift(1))
print ((mask2 & mask0).cumsum().add(1))
0    1
1    1
2    2
3    2
4    2
5    2
6    3
7    3
8    3
9    4
Name: Boolean_condition, dtype: int32

df['Event_number'] = (mask2 & mask0).cumsum().add(1).mask(mask0)
print (df)
   Timestamp  Boolean_condition  Event_number
0          1                  1           1.0
1          2                  1           1.0
2          3                  0           NaN
3          4                  1           2.0
4          5                  1           2.0
5          6                  1           2.0
6          7                  0           NaN
7          8                  0           NaN
8          9                  1           3.0
9         10                  0           NaN
```

**Timings**:

```
#[100000 rows x 2 columns
df = pd.concat([df]*10000).reset_index(drop=True)
df1 = df.copy()
df2 = df.copy()

def nick(df):
    isone = df.Boolean_condition[df.Boolean_condition.eq(1)]
    idx = isone.index
    grp = (isone != idx.to_series().diff().eq(1)).cumsum()
    df.loc[idx, 'Event_number'] = pd.Categorical(grp).codes + 1
    return df

def jez(df):
    mask0 = df.Boolean_condition.eq(0)
    mask2 = df.Boolean_condition.ne(df.Boolean_condition.shift(1))
    df['Event_number'] = (mask2 & mask0).cumsum().add(1).mask(mask0)
    return (df)

def jez1(df):
    mask0 = ~df.Boolean_condition
    mask2 = df.Boolean_condition.ne(df.Boolean_condition.shift(1))
    df['Event_number'] = (mask2 & mask0).cumsum().add(1).mask(mask0)
    return (df)

In [68]: %timeit (jez1(df))
100 loops, best of 3: 6.45 ms per loop

In [69]: %timeit (nick(df1))
100 loops, best of 3: 12 ms per loop

In [70]: %timeit (jez(df2))
100 loops, best of 3: 5.34 ms per loop
```

Comment: You can check my solution, it seems it is simplier, so 2.24 times faster.

Comment: @NickilMaveli - Hmmm, I know `numpy` solutions are obviously fast, but unfortunately complicated. So I like `pandas`, it is a bit slowier, but not so complicated and need less functions for same work. Also pandas has better support for `NaN` values, in `numpy` is necessary add some new functions for `NaN` support, so complicated solution is more complicated :( (generally, I am not sure about your solution).

Answer (score 3):

You could try the following:

1) Get all values of `True` instance (here, 1) which comprises of `isone`

2) Take it's corresponding set of indices and convert this to a series representation so that the new series has both it's index and values as the earlier computed indices. Perform the difference between successive rows and check if they are equal to 1. This becomes our boolean mask.

3) Compare `isone` with the obtained boolean mask and whenever they do not become equal, we take their cumulative sum (also known as adjacency check between elements). These help us in grouping purposes.

4) Using `loc` for the indices of `isone`, we assign the codes computed after changing the `grp` array to Categorical format to a new column created, *Event_number*.

---

```
isone = df.Bolean_condition[df.Bolean_condition.eq(1)]
idx = isone.index
grp = (isone != idx.to_series().diff().eq(1)).cumsum()
df.loc[idx, 'Event_number'] = pd.Categorical(grp).codes + 1
```

[image]

---

***Faster approach:***

Using only `numpy`:

1) Get it's array representation.

2) Compute the non-zero, here (`1's`) indices.

3) Insert `NaN` at the beginning of this array which would act as a starting point for us to perform difference taking successive rows into consideration.

4) Initialize a new array filled with `Nan's` of the same shape as that of the original array.

5) Whenever the difference between successive rows is not equal to 1, we take their cumulative sum, else they fall in the same group. These values get imputed at the indices where there were `1's` before.

6) Assign these back to the new column.

---

```
def nick(df):
    b = df.Bolean_condition.values
    slc = np.flatnonzero(b)
    slc_pl_1 = np.append(np.nan, slc)
    nan_arr = np.full(b.size, fill_value=np.nan)
    nan_arr[slc] = np.cumsum(slc_pl_1[1:] - slc_pl_1[:-1] != 1)
    df['Event_number'] = nan_arr
    return df
```

---

***Timings:***

For a `DF` of 10,000 rows:

```
np.random.seed(42)
df1 = pd.DataFrame(dict(
        Timestamp=np.arange(10000),
        Bolean_condition=np.random.choice(np.array([0,1]), 10000, p=[0.4, 0.6]))
                  )

df1.shape
# (10000, 2)

def jez(df):
    mask0 = df.Bolean_condition.eq(0)
    mask2 = df.Bolean_condition.ne(df.Bolean_condition.shift(1))
    df['Event_number'] = (mask2 & mask0).cumsum().mask(mask0)
    return (df)

nick(df1).equals(jez(df1))
# True

%%timeit
nick(df1)
1000 loops, best of 3: 362 µs per loop

%%timeit
jez(df1)
100 loops, best of 3: 1.56 ms per loop
```

---

For a `DF` containing 1 million rows:

```
np.random.seed(42)
df1 = pd.DataFrame(dict(
        Timestamp=np.arange(1000000),
        Bolean_condition=np.random.choice(np.array([0,1]), 1000000, p=[0.4, 0.6]))
                  )

df1.shape
# (1000000, 2)

nick(df1).equals(jez(df1))
# True

%%timeit
nick(df1)
10 loops, best of 3: 34.9 ms per loop

%%timeit
jez(df1)
10 loops, best of 3: 50.1 ms per loop
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work but might be a bit slow for a very long df.

```
df = pd.concat([df,pd.Series([0]*len(df), name = '2')], axis = 1)
if df.iloc[0,1] == 1:
        counter = 1
        df.iloc[0, 2] = counter
    else:
        counter = 0
        df.iloc[0,2] = 0
    previous = df.iloc[0,1]
    for y,x in df.iloc[1:,].iterrows():
        print(y)
        if x[1] == 1 and previous == 1:
            previous = x[1]
            df.iloc[y, 2] = counter
        if x[1] == 0:
            previous = x[1]
            df.iloc[y,2] = 0
        if x[1] == 1 and previous == 0:
            counter += 1
            previous = x[1]
            df.iloc[y,2] = counter
```

Answer (score 0):

A custom function does the trick. here is a solution in Matlab code:

```
Boolean_condition = [1 1 0 1 1 1 0 0 1 0];
Event_number = [NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA];
loop_event_number = 1;

for timestamp=1:10
if Boolean_condition(timestamp)==1
Event_number(timestamp) = loop_event_number;
last_event_number = loop_event_number;
else
loop_event_number = last_event_number +1;
end
end

% Event_number = 1 1 NA 2 2 2 NA NA 3 NA
```